# Display text from JSON object with HTML tag

Tags: html, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
comment: "Test Comments Feature<br>"
```

When I display it on my modalBox, `$('#myModal #comments'+i+'').text(test.comment);`

the HTML tag isn't being rendered:

Output: `Test Comments Feature<br>`

I tried using `JSON.parse(test.comment)` and `JSON.stringify(test.comment)`
But I could not achieve the desired result:

Test Comments Feature

What am I missing?
Can JSON objects render HTML automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text()` method will strip html tags, use `.html()` method instead:

```
$('#myModal #comments'+i+'').html(test.comment);
```